# Firebase Cloud Function Always Returns Null

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use the following function to interact with the Stripe API - it seems to work fine as the `key` object is logged correctly in the console and appears as expected.

```
exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
  const stripe_version = data.api_version;
  const customerId = data.customer_id;
  if (!stripe_version) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('missing-stripe-version','The stripe version has not been provided.');
  }
  if (customerId.length === 0) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('missing-customerID','The customer ID has not been provided.');
  }
  return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
      {customer: customerId},
      {stripe_version: stripe_version}
  ).then((key) => {
    console.log(key);
    return key;
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('stripe-error', err);
  });
});
```

However, when I call this function from my Swift iOS App, the `result?.data` is always nil.

```
let funcParams = ["api_version": apiVersion, "customer_id": "......"]
    functions.httpsCallable("createEphemeralKey").call(funcParams) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print(error)
            completion(nil,error)
        }
        if let json = result?.data as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print("success")
            print(json)
            completion(json, nil)
        } else {
            print("fail")
            print(result?.data)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because you don't return "data that can be JSON encoded" (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result)). The following should work:

```
....
).then((key) => {
  console.log(key);
  return {key: key};
})
....
```

Comment: key itself is a JSON object of the form:`{ id: '....',
  object: 'ephemeral_key',
  associated_objects: [ { type: 'customer', id: '....' } ],
  created: ...,
  expires: ...,
  livemode: false,
  secret: 'jijiijji' }`

Comment: OK. What if you try to return a simple JSON object `return {foo: 'bar'};`?

Comment: So the problem seems to come from the JSON "key" object that you get from Stripe. You may be able to reformat it depending on what you need in the front end....

Comment: I have no idea why, but I ran it again and it just worked....weirdest thing I've seen in a while